# C#: Error-Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>'

Tags: c#, c++, .net, generics, casting

I am trying to override the median value of a object EducationData, The model definition is as follows,

```
// EducationData model
[DataMember(Name = "DegreeConferred", Order = 1)]
public int DegreeConferred { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "NoOfInstitutions", Order = 3)]
public int NoOfInstitutions { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "Mean", Order = 6)]
public int Mean { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "Median", Order = 7)]
public IEnumerable<double> Median { get; set; }
```

CachedData is of type var, contains the ES query results of the education details as in the picture attached.

[image]

I have to override that median value with some alterations. Code segment I tried is as follows.

```
var resultData = cachedData.ToArray();
resultData[0].Mean = resultData[0].DegreeConferred / resultData[0].NoOfInstitutions; // calculated mean with no error
var updatedMedian = 7; // say for sample, because there is a need to override this queried value with some modification.
resultData[0].Median = updatedMedian; // Error line: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>'
```

Please Note: Changing the property to int in the model will affect the implementation in further places. So it will be better to do casting here.

I tried with ReSharper suggestion, like, but nothing works

```
resultData[0].Median = Convert.ToDouble(updatedMedian);
resultData[0].Median = IEnumerable<double>updatedMedian;
Also changing the property of updatedMedian will affect the calculation steps.
```

I have also tried some of the suggestion of SO as,

1. [LINQ: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487072/linq-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerableint)
2. [Linq Query : Cannot convert type IEnumerable<string> to string changing .ToString() to (string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512316/linq-query-cannot-convert-type-ienumerablestring-to-string-changing-tostrin)
3. [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809195/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerable)

I am struggling with this for past one and half days. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Median is not `int`,but `IEnumerable<double>`. You can't add elements to a IEnumerable. Change it to `List<double>` and use `resultData[0].Median.Add(7.0)`

Comment: Median seems to be an Array of double, setting it to an int cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would help!

```
        resultData[0].Median = new List<double>() {updatedMedian};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no type `var`, and `Median` is not an `int`, but rather an enumerable of double. That means that it (potentially) contains multiple values, not just one.

If you want to replace `Median` with a single value of 7, you can create an array:

```
resultData[0].Median = new [] { 7d };
```

Comment: Thats impressive! Thanks.
but incase i need to pass a variable say num instead of 7 a single constant value. What would be the case ?

Comment: @MJSuriya The same, `new [] { num }`. That's assuming `num` is a double, of course - otherwise you'll need to either convert it to double or create an array of double explicitly (`new double[]`).